# Accessing data in handlebars file

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How to access a variable in handlebars file that is declared in a JavaScript file. Accessing as below doesn't work.

In JavaScript file(script.js):

```
(function() {
  var dataForCreate = "Create";
})();
```

In Handlebar file(sample.hbs):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="createBtn">{{dataForCreate}}</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be having an index.html or some main html where you want to render/attach this template. `Sample.hbs` is just an template file, you first need to compile the hbs template to pass data to it.

**Step 1:**

In your script file access the template file say `sampleTemplate` and compile it using Handlebars helper.

```
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile( sampleTemplate );
```

**Step 2:**

Now you can pass the data to this compiled template as below -

```
var htmlTemplate = compiledTemplate({dataForCreate : "Create"});
```

**Step 3:**

Now you have the raw html partial/template ready to attach it to main html. Say you have a `div` container with id `sampleContainer` and you are using `jQuery` then -

```
$('#sampleContainer').html(htmlTemplate);
```